# Pagination does not work on page2 in php web page

Tags: javascript, php

Can someone help me on pagination syntax for php webpage. I have a set a pagination code to display 20 records per page. The records are displaying based on 'start date' and 'end date'.

The issue is, it works on *page 1* but when I click on *page 2* in pagination then it won't work. I assume the values of `$_POST['startdate']` and `$_POST['enddate]` are not forwarding on page2.

```html
  <html>
  <head> 
                <title></title> 
                <meta charset="utf-8"> 
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="multitab/bootstrap.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
                  <style> 
                 .inline{ 
                     display: inline-block; 
                     float: right; 
                     margin: 20px 0px; 
                 } 
                 input, button{ 
                     height: 34px; 
                 } 
                </style> 
              </head> 
              <body> 
              <form id="form1" name="form1" action="" method="post">
              <table>
             <tr>
                <td><b>Start date:</b></td>
                <td><input type="date" id="startdate" name="startdate" size="10"> </td>
                <td><b>End date:</b></td>
                <td><input type="date" id="enddate" name="enddate" size="10"   max=<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Search" name="Search"  onClick="return check()"></td>
              </tr>
             </table>
            </form>
             
             <?php 
                $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            if (!$con)
            {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            mysql_select_db("abc_db",$con);
                $limit = 20;   
                if (isset($_GET["page"])) {  
                  $pn  = $_GET["page"];  
                }  
                else {  
                  $pn=1;  
                };   
              
               if(isset($_POST['Search'])){
                      $startdate1 = $_POST['startdate'];
                      echo "Start date :  ".$startdate1", ";
                      $enddate1 = $_POST['enddate'];
                      echo "End date :  ".$enddate1;
                  }
                 $start_from = ($pn-1) * $limit;   
                 $serial = (($pn-1) * $limit) + 1; 
                 $today1= date("Y/m/d");
                 $days14_ago = date('Y/m/d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") , date("d") - 14, date("Y")));
              if ($startdate1 !=Null)  {
               $sql = "SELECT * FROM hd where datearrival='$startdate1' LIMIT $start_from, $limit";   
              } else if ($enddate1 !=Null)  {
               $sql = "SELECT * FROM hd where datearrival='$enddate1'  LIMIT $start_from, $limit";
               } else {
               $sql = "SELECT * FROM hd where datearrival between '$days14_ago' and '$today1' LIMIT $start_from, $limit";
              }
            
               if (($startdate !=Null) && ($enddate !=Null))  {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM hd where datearrival between '$startdate1' and '$enddate1' LIMIT $start_from, $limit";  
              } 
            
                 $rs_result = mysql_query ($sql);  
              
              ?> 
              <div class="container"> 
              <button style="height:25px;width:70px;" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Refresh</button>
                <br> 
                <div> 
                  <font face='cambria'><p><span style="display:inline-block; margin-left: 650px; ">
                   </span></p> </font>
                  <font face="Cambria" size="2"> <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered"> 
                    <thead> 
                     <tr> 
                      <th width="5%" valign="top">Sr#</th> 
                      <th width="10%" valign="top">Date arrival</th>
                      <th width="10%" valign="top">Pno</th>
                      <th width="10%" valign="top">First name</th> 
                                     
                      <th valign="top"></th> 
                      <th valign="top"></th> 
            
                    </tr> 
                    </thead> 
                    <tbody> 
                    <?php  
                      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs_result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
                      $pno1=$row['pno'];
                      $datearrival1=$row['datearrival'];
                      $sr_num = $serial++;
                    ?>   
                    <tr>   
                      <td><?php echo $sr_num; ?></td> 
                      <td><?php echo date("d/m/Y",  strtotime($row['datearrival'])); ?></td>   
                      <td><?php echo $row["pno"]; ?></td>   
                      <td><?php echo $row["first_name"]; ?></td>   
                     <td><p align="center"><a href='edit.php?$pno2=<?php echo $pno1 ?>&&$datearrival2=<?php echo $datearrival1 ?>' target='_blank()'> <font size="2">edit</font></a></td>
            
                      <td><p align="center"><a href='delete.php?$pno2=<?php echo $pno1 ?>&&$datearrival2=<?php echo $datearrival1 ?>' target='_blank()'> <font size="2">delete</font></a></td>
                    </tr>   
                    <?php  
                     
                    };   
                    ?>   
                    </tbody> 
                  </table> 
                  </font>
                  <div> 
                  <ul class="pagination"> 
                  <?php   
                    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hd where datearrival between '$startdate1' and '$enddate1'";   
                    $rs_result = mysql_query($sql);   
                    $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result);   
                    $total_records = $row[0];   
                    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit); 
                    $k = (($pn+4>$total_pages)?$total_pages-4:(($pn-4<1)?5:$pn));         
                    $pagLink = ""; 
                    if($pn>=2){ 
                        echo "<li><a href='qm.php?page=1'> << </a></li>"; 
                        echo "<li><a href='qm.php?page=".($pn-1)."'> < </a></li>"; 
                    } 
                    for ($i=-4; $i<=4; $i++) { 
                      if($k+$i==$pn) 
                        $pagLink .= "<li class='active'><a href='qm.php?page=".($k+$i)."'>".($k+$i)."</a></li>"; 
                      else
                        $pagLink .= "<li><a href='qm.php?page=".($k+$i)."'>".($k+$i)."</a></li>";   
                    };   
                    echo $pagLink; 
                    if($pn<$total_pages){ 
                        echo "<li><a href='qm.php?page=".($pn+1)."'> > </a></li>"; 
                        echo "<li><a href='qm.php?page=".$total_pages."'> >> </a></li>"; 
                    }     
                  ?> 
                  </ul> 
                  <div class="inline"> 
                  <input id="pn" type="number" min="1" max="<?php echo $total_pages?>" 
                  placeholder="<?php echo $pn."/".$total_pages; ?>" required> 
                  <button onclick="go2Page();">Go</button> 
                  </div> 
                  </div>  
                </div> 
              </div> 
             <script> 
                function go2Page() 
                { 
                    var pn = document.getElementById("pn").value; 
                    pn = ((pn><?php echo $total_pages; ?>)?<?php echo $total_pages; ?>:((pn<1)?1:pn)); 
                    window.location.href = 'qm.php?page='+pn; 
                } 
                
              /* start and end date- validation checks */
                function check(){
                  var startdatea=document.getElementById("startdate").value;        
                  var enddatea=document.getElementById("enddate").value;
                  if(Date.parse(startdatea)>Date.parse(enddatea)){
                  alert("Please select a different End Date.");
                  return false;
                  }
                }   
                </script> 
              </body> 
            </html>
```

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: @awan Your question was "Why my pagination code is not working for page 2 ?". In my opinion, Ingus an I answered this precise question, so consider checking one of those as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Doc Flandersao, Thanks. Yes it is working but still go2page() not working. Please uplift negative marking.

Comment: @awan Answers below clearly point what is wrong and how to make it work. As long as this question is answered, if you can't apply the answers to your buggy code, keep learning, and try hard. But don't consider the answers should be working code. I won't remove my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` superglobal variable is populated by PHP when a POST HTTP request is processed. This is the case on the request for page 1.

However, your `go2page()` function is mutating `location.href`, which generates a GET HTTP request, and so does pagination links.

You should append your `startdate` and `enddate` params to the pagination URLs, to forward your params to the next/previous requests :

```
qm.php?page=<YOUR-PAGE-NUMBER>&startdate=<YOUR-START-DATE>&enddate=<YOUR-END-DATE>';
```

And use `$_GET['startdate']` and `$_GET['enddate]` to retrieve those when processing GET requests.

More about $_POST https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

More about GET AND POST HTTP requests : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

Comment: @Flandersao, Tried the above code but function go2Page() still not working:
 <script> 
    function go2Page() 
    { 
        var pn = document.getElementById("pn").value; 
        pn = ((pn><?php echo $total_pages; ?>)?<?php echo $total_pages; ?>:((pn<1)?1:pn)); 
        //window.location.href = 'qmd.php?page='+pn; 
        startdatea = "<?php echo $_POST['startdate']?>";
        enddatea = "<?php echo $_POST['enddate']?>";
        window.location.href = 'qm.php?page="+pn."&startdate=".$startdatea."&enddate=".$enddatea."'; 
    } 
</script>

Comment: As stated by [@Ingus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459942/ingus), you'll have to test if your request is POST or GET to retrieve `startdate` and `enddate` from either $_GET or $_POST superglobal.

Make sure each link you generate (in `<a>`  tags or through javascript manipulation) contains your params.

Other consideration may require another question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your `isset($_POST['Search'])`

your code:

```
if(isset($_POST['Search'])){
    $startdate1 = $_POST['startdate'];
    echo "Start date :  ".$startdate1", ";
                  $enddate1 = $_POST['enddate'];
                  echo "End date :  ".$enddate1;
              }
```

possible working solution:

```
if(isset($_POST['Search'])){
    $startdate1 = $_POST['startdate'];
    echo "Start date :  ".$startdate1.", ";
                  $enddate1 = $_POST['enddate'];
                  echo "End date :  ".$enddate1;
              }
```

Though I didn't try it yet, but I assume this is the cause, pagination in page2 will not work since the code is not executed after the error which is the pagination for page2.

EDIT: The `.` fixes things.

```
echo "Start date :  ".$startdate1", ";
```

is different than

```
echo "Start date :  ".$startdate1.", ";
```

Comment: What have you changed there? your "new" code is the same as old one

Comment: @Ingus It's not the same, copying OP's codes makes your answer having the same error

Answer (score 0):

Add values of your `$_POST` inside links and use them as `$_GET` so you would use both.

```
$startdate1=$enddate1=null; //to hide notice
if(isset($_POST['Search'])){
      $startdate1 = $_POST['startdate'];
      echo "Start date :  ".$startdate1.", ";
      $enddate1 = $_POST['enddate'];
      echo "End date :  ".$enddate1;
} else if (!empty($_GET['startdate']) && !empty($_GET['enddate'])){
      $startdate1 = $_GET['startdate'];
      echo "Start date :  ".$startdate1.", ";
      $enddate1 = $_GET['enddate'];
      echo "End date :  ".$enddate1;
}

$pagLink .= "<li><a href='qm.php?page=".($k+$i)."&startdate=".startdate1."&enddate=".$enddate1."'>".($k+$i)."</a></li>";
```

For your need:

```
$pagLink = ""; 
if($pn>=2){ 
    echo "<li><a href='qm.php?page=1&startdate=".startdate1."&enddate=".$enddate1."'> << </a></li>"; 
    echo "<li><a href='qm.php?page=".($pn-1)."&startdate=".startdate1."&enddate=".$enddate1."'> < </a></li>"; 
} 
for ($i=-4; $i<=4; $i++) { 
  if($k+$i==$pn) 
    $pagLink .= "<li class='active'><a href='qm.php?page=".($k+$i)."&startdate=".startdate1."&enddate=".$enddate1."'>".($k+$i)."</a></li>"; 
  else
    $pagLink .= "<li><a href='qm.php?page=".($k+$i)."&startdate=".startdate1."&enddate=".$enddate1."'>".($k+$i)."</a></li>";   
};   
echo $pagLink; 
if($pn<$total_pages){ 
    echo "<li><a href='qm.php?page=".($pn+1)."&startdate=".startdate1."&enddate=".$enddate1."'> > </a></li>"; 
    echo "<li><a href='qm.php?page=".$total_pages."&startdate=".startdate1."&enddate=".$enddate1."'> >> </a></li>"; 
}
```

That would help you to move dates to next page.

You need to set it to all paging links. Also you can make extra if statement to not pass empty `GET`

**EDIT:**
As I already told: **You need to set it to all paging links. Also you can make extra if statement to not pass empty GET** (that includes javascript)

```
function go2Page() 
{ 
    var pn = document.getElementById("pn").value; 
    pn = ((pn><?php echo $total_pages; ?>)?<?php echo $total_pages; ?>:((pn<1)?1:pn)); 
    window.location.href = 'teztz.php?page='+pn+'&startdate=<?=startdate1;?>&enddate=<?=$enddate1;?>';
}
```

Comment: `$_GET` will not work since the `method` he used in the `<form>` tag is using `post`

Comment: why use `else if` if it will never gets executed then?

Comment: It will when there will be no `Search` used

Comment: it won't, seriously, unless you use `else` rather than `else if` though this will get an error too.

Comment: Dear Ingus, Thanks a ton. It is working well.
Two more things:
1. when I open the page, it shows a message :
     Notice: Undefined variable: startdate1, enddate1 in C:\wamp\www\qm.php on line 188
2. And If I click on > or >> sign, it shows an error message and not display anything. Do I would have to change something on the following lines:
 if($pn<$total_pages){ 
     echo "<li><a href='qm.php?page=".($pn+1)."'> > </a></li>"; 
     echo "<li><a href='qm.php?page=".$total_pages."'> >> </a></li>"; 
  }
A big thanks to you again.

Comment: @awan you need to set `&startdate=".startdate1."&enddate=".$enddate1."` to every paging link to make it work on every click (as in example) to hide notice you can add somewhere before if statement that sets these values `$startdate1=$enddate1=null;` Check my answers edit!

Comment: Dear Ingus, Thanks it's working now. Two points:
1.  For some reasons go2Page() not working:
 <script> 
    function go2Page() 
    { 
        var pn = document.getElementById("pn").value; 
        pn = ((pn><?php echo $total_pages; ?>)?<?php echo $total_pages; ?>:((pn<1)?1:pn)); 
        //window.location.href = 'qm.php?page='+pn; 
         startdatea = "<?php echo $_POST['startdate']?>";
         enddatea = "<?php echo $_POST['enddate']?>";
         window.location.href = 'qm.php? 
       page="+pn."&startdate=".$startdatea."&enddate=".$enddatea."'; 
      }

Comment: Dear Ingus, Here is my second query: 2. When I set $startdate1=$enddate1=null; it is working for the immediate section of code but when reaches to the next section, it set 'startdate' and enddate as null. Then sql query is not running. Could you please edit in my previous code..... . You really helped me a lot. Thank you in advance.